# Petsc not compiling c++ files

Tags: petsc

I'm having a problem where petsc is complaining about the type of PetscScalar (I get a whole bunch of errors from the c++ standard library that revolve around PetscScalar not defined).

I believe it is a problem with the way Petsc is compliled (I vaguely remember that Petsc can't seem to have both --with-c-support and --with-c++-support along with --with-scalar-type=complex, but I can't seem to figure out where that is stated.)

A sample of the errors I get (full version at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uTujfRUH)):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:550: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double std::__complex_abs(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:569: error: declaration of C function ‘double std::__complex_abs(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:566: error: previous declaration ‘float std::__complex_abs(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double std::__complex_abs(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:572: error: declaration of C function ‘long double std::__complex_abs(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:569: error: previous declaration ‘double std::__complex_abs(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:575: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:586: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double std::__complex_arg(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:596: error: declaration of C function ‘double std::__complex_arg(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:593: error: previous declaration ‘float std::__complex_arg(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double std::__complex_arg(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:599: error: declaration of C function ‘long double std::__complex_arg(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:596: error: previous declaration ‘double std::__complex_arg(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:602: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:616: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:628: error: template specialization with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:639: error: template with C linkage
at-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_cos(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:674: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_cos(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:671: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_cos(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_cos(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:677: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_cos(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:674: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_cos(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:680: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:690: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_cosh(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:704: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_cosh(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:701: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_cosh(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_cosh(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:707: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_cosh(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:704: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_cosh(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:710: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:720: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_exp(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:730: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_exp(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:727: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_exp(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_exp(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:733: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_exp(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:730: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_exp(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:736: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:747: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_log(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:757: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_log(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:754: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_log(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_log(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:760: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_log(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:757: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_log(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:763: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:772: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:778: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_exp(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:792: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sin(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:789: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_sin(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_exp(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:795: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_sin(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:792: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sin(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:798: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:808: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sinh(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:822: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sinh(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:819: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_sinh(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_sinh(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:825: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_sinh(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:822: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sinh(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:828: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:839: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sqrt(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:866: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sqrt(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:863: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_sqrt(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_sqrt(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:869: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_sqrt(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:866: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_sqrt(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:872: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:883: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_tan(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:893: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_tan(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:890: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_tan(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_tan(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:896: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_tan(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:893: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_tan(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:899: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:911: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_tanh(double __complex__)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:921: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_tanh(double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:918: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_tanh(float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_tanh(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:924: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_tanh(const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:921: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_tanh(double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:927: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:940: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:945: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:960: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: In function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_tan(const long double __complex__&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:971: error: declaration of C function ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_pow(double __complex__, double __complex__)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:967: error: previous declaration ‘float __complex__ std::__complex_pow(float __complex__, float __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:976: error: declaration of C function ‘long double __complex__ std::__complex_pow(const long double __complex__&, const long double __complex__&)’ conflicts with
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:971: error: previous declaration ‘double __complex__ std::__complex_pow(double __complex__, double __complex__)’ here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:979: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:990: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:1001: error: template specialization with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:1104: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:1113: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:1122: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:1131: error: template with C linkage
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/complex:1448: error: template with C linkage
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscmath.h:92: error: expected initializer before ‘PetscScalar’
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscmath.h:191: error: ‘PetscScalar’ does not name a type
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscmath.h:347: warning: ‘PetscIsInfOrNanScalar’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscmath.h:347: error: ‘PetscScalar’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscmath.h:367: error: ‘PetscScalar’ does not name a type
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscviewer.h:386: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscviewer.h:386: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘PetscScalar’ with no type
/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/include/petscviewer.h:387: error: ‘PetscScalar’ has not been declared
make: [bin/etom] Error 1 (ignored)
#-/usr/local/mpich2/bin/mpicc -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -g3  -o testmpi testmpi.o -lgsl  -L/usr/local/petsc-3.2-p6/lib  -lpetsc -lX11 -lpthread -llapack -lblas -L/central/intel/Compiler-11.1.072/mkl/lib/em64t -L/central/intel/Compiler-11.1.072/lib/intel64 -L/central/intel/Compiler-11.1.072/tbb/intel64/cc3.4.3_libc2.3.4_kernel2.6.9/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -ldl -lgcc_s -lifport -lifcore -limf -lsvml -lm -lipgo -lirc -lpthread -lirc_s -lm -lstdc++ -lstdc++ -ldl -lgcc_s -ldl 
#/bin/rm -f -f testmpi.o
```

Comment: Please post your configure.log to pastebin as well.

Comment: Is specific compilation advice on-topic here, or would this just be better on SO?

Comment: I was under the impression that library specific compilation/configuration issues were ok here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have quite a lot of issues to address first. For example, your GSL headers are not being found and your compiler is set up in some strict configuration where it errors on `long long`. Perhaps this means you have set `-pedantic -Werror`. The environment may also be messed up or you might have a stray open `extern "C" {` around some header includes.

Note that you will generally have type issues passing complex numbers between C and C++. In practice, C99 complex (see `complex.h`) is binary-compatible with C++ complex, so you can cast and still use the same interface.

If you still need help with PETSc, please send configure.log and any relevant build output to petsc-maint@mcs.anl.gov.